# how to bring a background job to foreground

Tags: linux, shell

in Linux/shell, how can I bring background jobs to foreground and vice versa?

Answer (score 49):

Did you use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, `SIGTSTP` or `SIGSTOP` to send it to the background? If so, you can bring it back to the foreground with the command

```
 fg
```

To get a list of all the stopped jobs and background jobs, use

```
jobs
```

Answer (score 25):

If you have a list of backgrounded jobs (as seen with the 'jobs' command),
you can pick a particular one with

```
fg %number
```

where *`number`* is the job number.

e.g.

```
jobs

[1]    suspended  top
[2]  - suspended  top
[3]  + suspended  top

fg %2
```