# How to bring a job to the foreground and allow user input from terminal

Tags: bash, job-control

Similar to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/83220/how-to-bring-a-background-job-to-foreground?newreg=09c46257b8174433a1984006bc604e2c) but different in an important way: I need to start a bunch of jobs from a script, and run them in the background.  Then, in order to manage them or check on their progress, I need to bring them to the foreground and allow user input.

What I'm currently doing is:

1. Start a bunch of jobs in a loop, e.g.

   ```
   for ip in $(cat ip-list.txt); do run-job.sh $ip &; done
   ```
2. Bring an individual job to the foreground with e.g.

   ```
   fg 1
   ```

This brings a job to the foreground, however there are two problems: I can't provide user input -- the process does not respond, as if the process receiving my input is the script that launched the job, not the job itself; also the variable $ip is displayed unevaluated, i.e. exactly as "$ip" rather than "192.168.1.34".  However, when I type 'jobs' I see all 10 jobs listed separately (but they all look exactly the same: "run-job.sh $ip".  I have to use ps to see which job is using which ip value.)

The behavior I'd like is the same as what I'd get if I started all of these jobs by typing them in individually, then hitting control-z to put them in the background.  If I do it that way, when I bring them to the foreground with fg, they allow user input directly to the process, and also the variable $ip is shown evaluated to "192.168.1.34".  However, manually typing the jobs in is not feasible for tens or scores of jobs.

Comment: Maybe run them in `screen`. For getting the variable expanded in a `jobs` listing, try starting it with `eval "./run-job.sh $ip &"`

Comment: As an aside, https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor

Comment: See also https://serverfault.com/questions/188936/writing-to-stdin-of-background-process